# Python Error <bound method Enemy.enemyhealth of <__main__.Enemy object at 0x0000025C21514A30>>

Tags: python, class, user-interface, inheritance

I am struggling with how to take user input in a child class and then pass values for health based on that user input of enemy type.

class Player:

```
def __init__(self, name, health, damage, defense):
self.name = name
self.health = health
self.damage = damage
self.defense = defense

def __str__(self):
return 'Player'

def characterCreate(self):
print('\nYour %s has been saved with the following information: ' % (self)
print('\nName: %s' % (self.name))
print('\nHealth: %s' % (self.health))
print('\nDamage: %s' % (self.damage))
print('\nDefense: %s' % (self.defense))
```

`info = Player(

```
name = input("\nPlease enter your player's name: \n"),
health = input("\nPlease enter your player's health: \n"),
damage = input("\nPlease enter your player's damage: \n"),
defense = input("\nPlease enter your player's defense: \n"))

info.characterCreater()
```

class Enemy(Player):

```
def __init__(self, name, health, damage, defense, enemytype):
    Player.__init__(self, name, health, damage, defense)
    self.type = enemytype
    

def enemyhealth(self):
    if enemytype == 'Villian':
        health = 25
    elif enemytype == 'Henchman':
        health = 15
    else:
        health = 5

def characterCreate(self):
    print('\nYour %s has been saved with the following information: ' % (self))
    print('\nName: %s' % (self.name))
    print('\nHealth: %s' % (self.enemyhealth))
    print('\nDamage: %s' % (self.damage))
    print('\nDefense: %s' % (self.defense))
    print('\nType: %s' % (self.type))

def __str__(self):
    return 'Enemy'
```

info2 = Enemy(
name = input("\nPlease enter your enemy's name: \n"),
enemytype = input("\nPlease choose your enemy's type (Villian, Henchman, Mercenaries): \n"),
health = 25,
damage = 20,
defense = 5)

info2.characterCreate()

Comment: You see `bound method...` when printing because you are printing `self.enemyhealth` which is indeed a method. You probably need to call it, and make it return something. Can you provide the code for the `Player` class? Also note that you are using `enemytype` instead of `self.enemytype` in the `enemyhealth` function.

Comment: I was able to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked a bunch of things to make it work in a way I find reasonable, and added comments to explain the changes.

The main error, as I said in the comment, was printing `self.enemyhealth` which is a method.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, health, damage, defense):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage
        self.defense = defense

    def __str__(self):
        return "Player"

    def characterCreate(self):
        print("\nYour %s has been saved with the following information: " % (self))
        print("\nName: %s" % (self.name))
        print("\nHealth: %s" % (self.health))
        print("\nDamage: %s" % (self.damage))
        print("\nDefense: %s" % (self.defense))


class Enemy(Player):
    def __init__(self, name, health, damage, defense, enemytype):
        Player.__init__(self, name, health, damage, defense)
        self.enemytype = enemytype

        # call enemyhealth to setup the initial value?
        # or use the health provided as arg as done in Player.__init__?
        self.enemyhealth()

    def enemyhealth(self):
        # use self.enemytype (enemytype is not defined in this func)
        if self.enemytype == "Villain":
            # save the health as an attribute
            self.health = 25
        elif self.enemytype == "Henchman":
            self.health = 15
        else:
            self.health = 5

    def characterCreate(self):
        print("\nYour %s has been saved with the following information: " % (self))
        print("\nName: %s" % (self.name))
        # use the instance attribute .health directly
        print("\nHealth: %s" % (self.health))
        print("\nDamage: %s" % (self.damage))
        print("\nDefense: %s" % (self.defense))
        print("\nType: %s" % (self.enemytype))

    def __str__(self):
        return "Enemy"


info = Player(
    name=input("\nPlease enter your player's name: \n"),
    health=input("\nPlease enter your player's health: \n"),
    damage=input("\nPlease enter your player's damage: \n"),
    defense=input("\nPlease enter your player's defense: \n"),
)
info.characterCreate()

info2 = Enemy(
    name=input("\nPlease enter your enemy's name: \n"),
    enemytype=input(
        "\nPlease choose your enemy's type (Villain, Henchman, Mercenaries): \n"
    ),
    # note that the health will be overwritten by the call to `self.enemyhealth`
    health=25,
    damage=20,
    defense=5,
)
info2.characterCreate()
```

Cheers!

Comment: thank you.  It was the calling of the method, I was guess I was putting it in the wrong place originally and was getting errors so I took it out. The other stuff, I would have figured out...again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

calling a field type is going to cause problems and self is missing from the enemyhealth method.

```
def __init__(self, name, health, damage, defense, enemytype):
    Player.__init__(self, name, health, damage, defense)
    self.enemytype = enemytype
    

def enemyhealth(self):
    if self.enemytype == 'Villian':
        self.health = 25
    elif self.enemytype == 'Henchman':
        self.health = 15
    else:
        self.health = 5
```

you would also need to change `print('\nType: %s' % (self.type))`  to `print('\nType: %s' % (self.enemytype))`

though without more context i'm not sure what this code is attempting to do